# Schedule E: What "Type of Property" do I use when renting out a room?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, rental-property

If I rent 1 out of 4 bedrooms in my house, then 25% is rental and 75% is personal.

In filling out Schedule E, I use my house address in Line 1a.

Line 1B is for "Type of Property".

How do I indicate that it is a room in my house, and that it is 25% of the house?

I use that fraction to calculate the expenses, but where do I specifically state that that is the portion of house being rented?